# _MoveTempFilesIntoFinalDestinationFn/WriteToFiles do not move temp file to final destination as expected - what did I miss?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Thanks for your time to reviewing my question.

I was using WriteToFiles to sink text contents.

Here is the code:

```
p_coll_bounded | f"Sink - {notes}" >> WriteToFiles(path=path,
                                                   file_naming=naming_convention)

# naming_convention is defined as below:

def ce_file_naming_fn(*args):
    window, pane, shard_index, total_shards, compression, destination = args

    window_time_utc = window.start.to_utc_datetime()
    sub_dir = FileSystems.join(
        destination,
        f"year={window_time_utc.year}",
        f"month={window_time_utc.month}",
        f"day={window_time_utc.day}",
        f"hour={window_time_utc.hour}",
        f"minute={window_time_utc.minute}"
    )
    fn = FileSystems.join(sub_dir, f"{int(window_time_utc.timestamp())}")
    return fn
```

Somehow It never successfully moved the temp file to final designated file path.

I have no ideal why....

in the source code `/apache_beam/io/fileio.py` ([source code here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fe41855c322e31dee2077d8cf3b95ad2fba85870/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L689) I can see my code always lead to `BeamIOError`.

But I have no idea why the error does not matter. The files just do not get moved to the place where it suppose to be. I almost get depressed by this behaviour..

The error is captured by this [line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fe41855c322e31dee2077d8cf3b95ad2fba85870/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L690)

The error:

```
{BeamIOError}Rename operation failed with exceptions {('TestFileIO/ces/.tempc05b5f30-a523-4d01-9dab-b808ff241b33/4558506177896344154_85a8cf39-c10c-491f-aa2e-6c95141c3eae', 'TestFileIO/ces/source-1/year=2022/month=10/day=19/hour=2/minute=47/1666108065'): OSError(FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))}
```

#### Basically it is complaining the destination directory does not exist yet.

As you can see beam is trying to move file
`TestFileIO/ces/.tempc05b5f30-a523-4d01-9dab-b808ff241b33/4558506177896344154_85a8cf39-c10c-491f-aa2e-6c95141c3eae` to `TestFileIO/ces/source-1/year=2022/month=10/day=19/hour=2/minute=47/1666108065`

(the sub dir `TestFileIO/ces/source-1/year=2022/month=10/day=19/hour=2/minute=47/` does not exist yet in the system)

Comment: Hi @RuodingTian, Can you clarify more on your use case? Where are you trying to move the temp file to the final destination path, are you using any external source? Also, can you provide the full error message you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @PrajnaRaiT. The error is captured by https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fe41855c322e31dee2077d8cf3b95ad2fba85870/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L690.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have found the answer. :)

The problem happens only when `WriteToFiles` is trying to write to a local file system.

The problem is automatically gone if you are writing into a GCS bucket.